# Why number of units is used in the out projection for seq2seq model in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I don't understand why number of units in a layer is used as a parameter for the out projection in the seq2seq model. Concretely, here is the code that confuses me (line 98 in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py)

```
w_t = tf.get_variable("proj_w", [self.target_vocab_size, size], dtype=dtype)
```

Here, size is number of units in each layer of the model. Why?

I thought it should be num_samples instead (most often, size and num_samples are both 512). However, when I tried to set num_samples to 500, and size to 512, and run the training, it complains that the dimension does not match.

Can someone please help me to understand this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The weight matrix is mapping from model state to vocabulary. The sampling is just to avoid evaluating the whole softmax; the number of samples could vary across runs for a fixed model.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I understand the purpose of the output projection. It maps large vocabulary size to a smaller size (x) for calculating softmax at training time, and maps x back to the vocabulary size at test/prediction time. That's why I don't understand why the x I referred should be something related to number of units in a layer.